# Sympy's subs limitations

Tags: python, sympy, substitution, symbolic-math

I am working with some long equations but not really complex, and I wanted to use **sympy** to simplify and "factorize" them. But I have encountered a few problems. Here is a list of some minimal examples:

**Problem 1: symmetry**

```
from sympy import *
from __future__ import division
a = symbols('a')
b = symbols('b')
expr = 1/12*b + 1
expr.subs(1/12*b, a)
expr.subs(b*1/12, a)
```

The first line gives the expected result (ie. `a+1`) while in the second one there is no substitution.

**Problem 2: factorized expressions**

Some parts of the expression are factorized and when I expand the expression they get simplified, thus making the substitution impossible. For example

```
(((x+1)**2-x).expand()).subs(x**2+2*x, y+1)
```

will give `x^2+x+1` and what I am looking for is `y+2-x`.

**Question**

Is there a way to solve these problems ? Or maybe I should use another symbolic mathematical tool ? Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Relevant to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645574/1959808

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a major gotcha in SymPy, which is that, because of the way Python works, `number/number` gives a floating point (or does integer division if you use Python 2 and don't `from __future__ import division`).

In the first case and in your original expression, Python evaluates `1/12*b` from left to right. `1/12` is evaluated by Python to give `0.08333333333333333`, which is then multiplied by `b`. In the second case, `b*1` is evaluated as `b`. Then `b/12` is evaluated by SymPy (because `b` is a SymPy object), to give `Rational(1, 12)*b`.

Due to the inexact nature of floating point numbers, SymPy does not see the float `0.08333333333333333` as equal to the rational `1/12`.

There is some more discussion of this issue [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html). As a workaround, you should avoid direct `integer/integer` without wrapping it somehow, so that SymPy can create a rational. The following will all create a rational:

```
b/12
Rational(1, 12)*b
S(1)/12*b
```

---

For `(((x+1)**2-x).expand()).subs(x**2+2*x, y+1)` the issue is that `x**2 + 2*x` does not appear exactly in the expression, which is `x**2 + x + 1`. SymPy generally only replaces things that it sees exactly.

It seems you don't mind adding and subtracting an `x` to make the replacement work. So I would suggest doing instead `(((x+1)**2-x).expand()).subs(x**2, y+1 - 2*x)`. By only substituting a single term (`x**2`), the substitution will always work, and the `2*x` will cancel out to leave whatever `x` term remains (in this case, `-x`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution to your problems:

```
from sympy import *

a = symbols('a')
b = symbols('b')
expr = 1 / 12 * b + 1
print(expr.subs((1 / 12) * b, a))
print(expr.subs(b * (1 / 12), a))

x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y')
expr = ((x + 1)**2 - x).expand()
print(expr.subs(x**2 + x, y - x + 1))
```

Comment: For the first problem I think there is a `from __future__ import division
`, with this addition I tried and it's working. However, I don't understand why.
For the second problem, this really doesn't solve my problem. What I gave here are minimal examples but in reality the equations are really long. I cannot really 'cheat' the results. And I definitely can't change the value to be substituted...
Thanks for answering !

Comment: For the second question maybe my question is "is it possible to expand without simplifying" ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding problem 1, note that `1/12*b` and `b*1/12` are *not* the same thing in sympy. The first is a floating number mutliplied by a symbol, whereas the second is an exact symbolic expression (you can check it out by a simple print statement). Since `expr` contains `1/12*b`, it is not surprising that the second `subs` does not work.

Regarding problem 2, the `subs` rule you provide is ambiguous. In particular the substitution rule implies that equation `x**2+2*x==y+1`. However, this equation has many interpretations, e.g,

`x**2 == y + 1 - 2*x` (this is the one you consider),

`x**2 + x == y + 1 - x`,

`x == (y + 1 - x**2)/2`,

For this reason, I consider sympy refusing to perform a substitution is actually a correct approach.

If it is the first interpretation you want, it is better to explicitly provide it in the `subs` rule, i.e.,

```
(((x+1)**2-x).expand()).subs(x**2, -2*x + y + 1)
```

> `-x + y + 2`