# general expression substitution in sympy

Tags: sympy

I have two univariate functions, `f(x)` and `g(x)`, and I'd like to substitute `g(x) = y` to rewrite `f(x)` as some `f2(y)`.

Here is a simple example that works:

```
In [240]: x = Symbol('x')

In [241]: y = Symbol('y')

In [242]: f = abs(x)**2 + 6*abs(x) + 5

In [243]: g = abs(x)

In [244]: f.subs({g: y})
Out[244]: y**2 + 6*y + 5
```

But now, if I try a slightly more complex example, it fails:

```
In [245]: h = abs(x) + 1

In [246]: f.subs({h: y})
Out[246]: Abs(x)**2 + 6*Abs(x) + 5
```

Is there a general approach that works for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `abs(x)**2 + 6*abs(x) + 5` does not actually contain `abs(x) + 1` anywhere, so there is nothing to substitute for.

One can imagine changing it to `abs(x)**2 + 5*(abs(x) + 1) + abs(x)`, with the substitution result being `abs(x)**2 + 5*y + abs(x)`. Or maybe changing it to `abs(x)**2 + 6*(abs(x) + 1) - 1`, with the result being `abs(x)**2 + 6*y - 1`.  There are other choices too. What should the result be?

There is no general approach to this task because it's not a well-defined task to begin with.

In contrast, the substitution `f.subs(abs(x), y-1)` is a clear instruction to replace all occurrences of abs(x) in the expression tree with `y-1`. It returns `6*y + (y - 1)**2 - 1`.

The substitution above of `abs(x) + 1` in `abs(x)**2 + 6*abs(x) + 5` is a clear instruction too: to find exact occurrences of the expression `abs(x) + 1` in the syntax tree of the expression `abs(x)**2 + 6*abs(x) + 5`, and replace those subtrees with the syntax tree of the expression `abs(x) + 1`. There is a caveat about [heuristics though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645574/1959808).

Aside: in addition to `subs` SymPy has a method [`.replace`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.replace) which supports wildcards, but I don't expect it to help here. In my experience, it is overeager to replace:

```
>>> a = Wild('a')
>>> b = Wild('b')
>>> f.replace(a*(abs(x) + 1) + b, a*y + b)
5*y/(Abs(x) + 1) + 6*y*Abs(x*y)/(Abs(x) + 1)**2 + (Abs(x*y)/(Abs(x) + 1))**(2*y/(Abs(x) + 1))
```

#### Eliminate a variable

There is no "eliminate" in SymPy. One can attempt to emulate it with `solve` by introducing another variable, e.g.,

```
fn = Symbol('fn')
solve([Eq(fn,  f), Eq(abs(x) + 1, y)], [fn, x])
```

which attempts to solve for "fn" and "x", and therefore the solution for "fn" is an expression without x. **If this works**

In fact, it does not work with `abs()`; solving for something that sits inside an absolute value is not implemented in SymPy. Here is a workaround.

```
fn, ax = symbols('fn ax')
solve([Eq(fn,  f.subs(abs(x), ax)), Eq(ax + 1, y)], [fn, ax])
```

This outputs `[(y*(y + 4), y - 1)]` where the first term is what you want; a solution for `fn`.

Comment: The result I desire is an expression that eliminates `x` entirely. I don't necessarily expect `subs()` to be the right function for that purpose; my question is whether there is any way to tell sympy to give me an expression that doesn't contain `x`.

Comment: Thanks. The workaround works here, but sounds like there is not a general approach.