# Sympy: Multivariate Polynomial Composition

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I have a complex multivariate polynomial in variables (x,y) and I need to obtain a new polynomial in variables (a,b) by setting

```
x = (a+b) / sqrt(2)
y = -i (a-b) / sqrt(2)
```

Which you might recognise as a change of variables from/to complex coordinates.

I am aware of the function "compose", but it seems to only replace the "x" variable of my polynomial, is there a way to do multivariate composition?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you not just use `subs` for this?

Comment: which is defined here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/cb57534f1d4d5dfc4c887ce4ffba608a5b04e949/sympy/core/basic.py#L764-L876

Comment: Relevant also to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32930285/1959808

Comment: Regarding substitution of general subexpressions using the method `subs`, the following is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45383358/1959808

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, simultaneous substitution is possible using the method [`sympy.core.basic.Basic.subs`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/cb57534f1d4d5dfc4c887ce4ffba608a5b04e949/sympy/core/basic.py#L764-L876), for example:

```py
import sympy

a, b, x, y = sympy.symbols('a b x y')

poly = sympy.poly(x + y)
let = {x: (a + b) / sympy.sqrt(2), y: - sympy.I * (a - b) / sympy.sqrt(2)}
new_poly = poly.subs(let, simultaneous=True)
# at this point, `new_poly` is:
# Poly(sqrt(2)*a/2 - sqrt(2)*I*a/2 + sqrt(2)*b/2 + sqrt(2)*I*b/2,
#      sqrt(2)*(a + b)/2, -sqrt(2)*I*(a - b)/2, domain='EX')
# so the following assertions pass
assert str(new_poly.gens) == '(sqrt(2)*(a + b)/2, -sqrt(2)*I*(a - b)/2)', (
    new_poly.gens)
assert new_poly.monoms() == [(0, 0)], new_poly.monoms()
# worth remarking that
assert new_poly.free_symbols == {a, b}, new_poly.free_symbols
# by converting from an instance of the class `sympy.polys.polytools.Poly`
# to an instance of the class `sympy.core.expr.Expr`, and
# back to an instance of the class `sympy.polys.polytools.Poly`,
# the generators become as expected
new_poly = new_poly.as_expr().as_poly()
    # the previous statement is equivalent, as far as I know,
    # to the statement:
    # `new_poly = sympy.poly(new_poly.as_expr())`
    # However, the latter raises an exception for some expressions
    # (for an example, see below).
    # The exception is avoided by using the expression method `as_poly`.
assert str(new_poly.gens) == '(a, b, sqrt(2))', new_poly.gens
assert new_poly.monoms() == [(1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1)], new_poly.monoms()
assert new_poly.free_symbols == {a, b}, new_poly.free_symbols
print(f'polynomial: {new_poly}')
print(f'generators: {new_poly.gens}')
print(f'monomials: {new_poly.monoms()}')
print(f'coefficients: {new_poly.coeffs()}')
```

which prints:

```
polynomial: Poly((1/2 - I/2)*a*(sqrt(2)) + (1/2 + I/2)*b*(sqrt(2)), a, b, sqrt(2), domain='QQ_I')
generators: (a, b, sqrt(2))
monomials: [(1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1)]
coefficients: [1/2 - I/2, 1/2 + I/2]
```

and ensures, as requested in the comments, that the resulting polynomial have as [generators](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/basics.html#polynomials) the expressions we would expect if we constructed the new polynomial from scratch, i.e.,

```py
import sympy

a, b = sympy.symbols('a b')
expr = (
    (1/2 - sympy.I/2) * a * (sympy.sqrt(2))
    + (1/2 + sympy.I/2) * b *(sympy.sqrt(2)))
new_poly = expr.as_poly()
assert str(new_poly.gens) == '(a, b, sqrt(2))', new_poly.gens
```

In fact, the polynomial obtained in this way is equal but slightly differently represented, specifically with decimals instead of fractions, i.e., `new_poly` in this case is `Poly((0.5 - I/2)*a*(sqrt(2)) + (0.5 + I/2)*b*(sqrt(2)), a, b, sqrt(2), domain='EX')`.

It is worth noting that the above conversion from a polynomial to an expression and back to a polynomial is needed only if `poly` is an instance of the class `sympy.polys.polytools.Poly`, as it is above.

Working with expressions avoids the need to convert the final result from a polynomial to an expression and back to a polynomial. Instead, a conversion from expression to polynomial suffices, as follows (the conversion to polynomial is needed in case one is interested to call the method `monoms`, because expressions are instances of the class `sympy.core.expr.Expr`, which does not have a method `monoms`):

```py
import sympy

a, b, x, y = sympy.symbols('a b x y')

poly = x + y
let = {x: (a + b) / sympy.sqrt(2), y: - sympy.I * (a - b) / sympy.sqrt(2)}
new_poly = poly.subs(let, simultaneous=True)
# at this point, `new_poly` is an instance of the
# class `sympy.core.expr.Expr`,
# so it does not have methods `monoms` and `gens`,
# thus a conversion to polynomial is needed.
# This conversion creates the expected generators, monomials,
# and coefficients, as follows.
new_poly = new_poly.as_expr().as_poly()
assert str(new_poly.gens) == '(a, b, sqrt(2))', new_poly.gens
assert new_poly.monoms() == [(1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1)], new_poly.monoms()
assert new_poly.free_symbols == {a, b}, new_poly.free_symbols
print(f'polynomial: {new_poly}')
print(f'generators: {new_poly.gens}')
print(f'monomials: {new_poly.monoms()}')
print(f'coefficients: {new_poly.coeffs()}')
```

This block of code prints the same output as the first block of code.

And repeating the above two approaches to the polynomial of interest `x**2 + y**2` (this polynomial was noted in a comment):

```py
import sympy

a, b, x, y = sympy.symbols('a b x y')

poly = sympy.poly(x**2 + y**2)
let = {x: (a + b) / sympy.sqrt(2), y: - sympy.I * (a - b) / sympy.sqrt(2)}
new_poly = poly.subs(let, simultaneous=True)
# at this point, `new_poly` is:
# Poly(2*a*b, sqrt(2)*(a + b)/2, -sqrt(2)*I*(a - b)/2, domain='ZZ[a,b]')
# so the following assertions pass
assert str(new_poly.gens) == '(sqrt(2)*(a + b)/2, -sqrt(2)*I*(a - b)/2)', (
    new_poly.gens)
assert new_poly.monoms() == [(0, 0)], new_poly.monoms()
# worth remarking that
assert new_poly.free_symbols == {a, b}, new_poly.free_symbols
# by converting from an instance of the class `sympy.polys.polytools.Poly`
# to an instance of the class `sympy.core.expr.Expr`, and
# back to an instance of the class `sympy.polys.polytools.Poly`,
# the generators become as expected
new_poly = new_poly.as_expr().as_poly()
assert str(new_poly.gens) == '(a, b)', new_poly.gens
assert new_poly.monoms() == [(1, 1)], new_poly.monoms()
assert new_poly.free_symbols == {a, b}, new_poly.free_symbols
print(f'polynomial: {new_poly}')
print(f'generators: {new_poly.gens}')
print(f'monomials: {new_poly.monoms()}')
print(f'coefficients: {new_poly.coeffs()}')
```

which prints the output:

```
polynomial: Poly(2*a*b, a, b, domain='ZZ')
generators: (a, b)
monomials: [(1, 1)]
coefficients: [2]
```

and the code block:

```py
import sympy

a, b, x, y = sympy.symbols('a b x y')

poly = x**2 + y**2
let = {x: (a + b) / sympy.sqrt(2), y: - sympy.I * (a - b) / sympy.sqrt(2)}
new_poly = poly.subs(let, simultaneous=True)
# at this point, `new_poly` is an instance of the
# class `sympy.core.expr.Expr`,
# so it does not have methods `monoms` and `gens`,
# thus a conversion to polynomial is needed.
# This conversion creates the expected generators, monomials,
# and coefficients, as follows.
new_poly = new_poly.as_expr().as_poly()
    # if the previous statement is replaced with the statement:
    # `new_poly = sympy.poly(new_poly.as_expr())`
    # then an exception is raised:
    # `CoercionFailed: expected an integer, got 1/2`
assert str(new_poly.gens) == '(a, b)', new_poly.gens
assert new_poly.monoms() == [(1, 1)], new_poly.monoms()
assert new_poly.free_symbols == {a, b}, new_poly.free_symbols
print(f'polynomial: {new_poly}')
print(f'generators: {new_poly.gens}')
print(f'monomials: {new_poly.monoms()}')
print(f'coefficients: {new_poly.coeffs()}')
```

which prints the same output as the previous code block.

Additional documentation about the method `subs` can be found [in the `sympy` documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution) (even though there the discussion is in terms of expression instances, it applies also to instances of polynomials, because both subclass the class `Basic` without overriding the method `subs`).

Note also that substitution of subexpressions that are not identifiers works roughly by searching the syntax tree of the expression for subtrees that match the syntax tree of the subexpressions to be substituted, and replacing the subtrees. There is a caveat about some heuristics though, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645574/1959808), and in the docstring of the method `sympy.core.basic.Basic.subs`.

(Also, a multiplication sign appears to be missing in the question.)

Comment: Thanks! However I am still having issues with this change of variables. The new polynomial has the incorrect generators: they are not a and b, but some other expressions. This is problematic because, by calling "monoms()" I obtain a single degree zero monomial, whose "coefficient" is the whole polynomial. Effectively, it thinks that the polynomial is over C[a,b]

Comment: Good point, I updated the answer to avoid this. I assume that by "as symbols" you mean the polynomial's generators, because `assert new_poly.free_symbols == {sympy.Symbol('a'), sympy.Symbol('b')}` passes, whereas indeed `str(new_poly.gens)` is `'(sqrt(2)*(a + b)/2, -sqrt(2)*I*(a - b)/2)'` (the expressions from the change of variables, as you remarked).

Comment: In my first version of the answer, I was actually constructing expressions, which do not have a `monoms` method. I assume that by ".monoms()" you mean the method  `sympy.polys.polytools.Poly.monoms`. So a conversion to polynomials is needed. Working with expressions, and converting the final result to a polynomial, the generators are as expected. Only working with polynomials directly yields an unexpected result, which then necessitates converting to an expression and back to a polynomial.

Comment: For the polynomial `x**2 + y**2`, I do not get an empty `list` (the updated answer has more details), though indeed `monoms` does not return what would be expected by comparing to constructing the same polynomial from scratch. I do not know whether the unexpected representation of the resulting polynomial in terms of generators, monomials, and coefficients could be considered a bug in the package `sympy`. Also, I assume you mean `poly = x**2 + y**2` (writing `x^2` raises `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'Symbol' and 'int'`).

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out in a minute. Yes, I meant the proper python syntax. I'm jumping back and forward between Latex and Python, so my notation is a bit messy!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean that you want to rewrite a and b as functions of x and y?

```
from sympy.abc import a,b,x,y
from sympy import I, sqrt, solve
eqs = [
x - (a+b) / sqrt(2),
y - -I* (a-b) / sqrt(2)]
>>> solve(eqs,(a,b))
{a: sqrt(2)*x/2 + sqrt(2)*I*y/2, b: sqrt(2)*x/2 - sqrt(2)*I*y/2}
```

Comment: No, I mean I have (for instance) p(x,y) = x^2 + xy + y^4 and I want to obtain p( x(a,b), y(a,b) ), so p(a,b)