# Sympy subs does not working for subexpression. Is there a way to solve this?

Tags: python, matlab, math, sympy, algebra

`subs` (from `sympy` library in Python) does not replace a subexpression in all cases except simple ones. MATLAB copes with this task perfectly. Is it possible to somehow achieve the same result as in MATLAB?

**Sympy**

[image: sympy]

**MATLAB**

[image: matlab]

Comment: You better post your code as text instead of images.

Comment: I love this question, but I fear the answer is that `sympy` is basically only capable of substituting expressions as present in the current representation. See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633262/sympy-substitute-mathematical-expression.

I guess you have to contribute to [`sympy`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy) to improve it ;)

Comment: You can use `e.subs(x, z - y)`

Comment: Print the `f` before the subs.  `sympy` expanded it to the [3] form on creation, so the `x+y` expression doesn't exist in `f`.

Comment: The substitution works in `g = parse_expr('-1/(2*(x+y))',evaluate=False)` because it does not expand the multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fails because the product `2*(x + y)` automatically expands to the sum of `2x + 2*y`, as [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) points out. And [@oscarbenjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9450991/oscar-benjamin) points out that re-arranging your substitution so it targets only an atomic part of the expression you desire to replace will work.

In addition, if you backsubstitute to restore the original atom you will see if the substitution was not able to be fully done while retaining the original variables:

```py
>>> f = (x + y)**2 + 1/(4*x + 4*y + sin(2*x + 2*y))
>>> (f+x).subs(x,z-y).subs(y,z-x)
x + z**2 + 1/(4*z + sin(2*z))
```